# Get system name and label from term in Display Template

Tags: taxonomy, display-template

I'm retrieving a taxonomy field from a search request in a Display Template.
The content of the field looks like this:

```
termField.inputValue
"GP0|#f76c1099-c0e6-f6df-7814-cc7ea541b129

L0|#0f76c1099-c0e6-f6df-7814-cc7ea541b129|The-term-name

GTSet|#49cbba15-ddc7-41ed-8a84-54426c040012"
```

So now I want to render the system name ("The-term-name") and the label of the term. What is the best approach to do that? Do I have to parse the string value on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only want to parse the returned term and not lookup alternate labels and such you can use the built-in `$getItemValue` function. It takes the context and the mapped name of your managed property:

```
$getItemValue(ctx, mappedManagedProperty')
```

The mapping is the name you specify in the `ManagedPropertyMapping` attribute within the display template. Say your display template specified these mappings:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">
  'Title':'Title',
  'Path':'Path',
  'Description':'Description',
  'EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER',
  'LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime',
  'CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus',
  'DocId':'DocId',
  'HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary',
  'HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties',
  'FileExtension':'FileExtension',
  'ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime',
  'ParentLink':'ParentLink',
  'FileType':'FileType',
  'IsContainer':'IsContainer',
  'SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension',
  'DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor',
  'ServerRedirectedURL':'ServerRedirectedURL'
  'Subject': 'owstaxIdSubject'
</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

Where `owstaxIdSubject` is a taxonomy field managed property with a value like so:

```
"SharePoint|#f76c1099-c0e6-f6df-7814-cc7ea541b129
```

You would write this:

```
$getItemValue(ctx, 'Subject')
```

to render something like this:

```
SharePoint
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the term and its information by Managed Metadata API (very slow) or lookup in the local list (unsupported). But I'd make a REST call to the item and get directly this fields display value. In that way you do not need to handle different field types and scenarios.

Comment: I already have the term field at hand. It's an JavaScript object of type "Srch.ValueInfo". And the only useful stuff is the property "InputValue" as described in my question.

When I want to get the display name I have to use the Taxonomy API, I think that's right. But what's the best way to get the system name that's already contained in "inputValue"? IsN't there any build in function or have I do the parsing on my own? Am I the first person that is obtaining a taxonomy field via a Search Web Part with Display Template?!